# Display dynamic content in Angular Modal from parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using [angular-modal-service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service). I wish to modify the content of modal body as custom input text from the user. My `index.html` looks like :

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="notify.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" ng-model="custom_text" />
<input type="button" value="Click here for notification" ng- click="showNotification()" />
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js :

```
var app = angular.module("someApp", ['angularModalService']);

app.controller("mainController", function($scope, ModalService){
$scope.showNotification = function(){
    document.getElementById('my_text').innerHTML = $scope.custom_text;
    alert($scope.custom_text);
    ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: "notify.html",
      controller: "YesNoController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {
        $scope.message = result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No";
      });
    });
}

});

app.controller('YesNoController', ['$scope', 'close', function($scope, close) {

  $scope.close = function(result) {
  close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
  };

}]);
```

My notify.html has :

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close(false)" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Yes or No?</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><span id="my_text"></span></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" ng-click="close(false)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="close(true)" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I am actually trying to modify notify.html modal body in the controller by accessing it through DOM. But it is giving me the error : Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

How can I do this. Please help.

Comment: Please see answers below, but as a side not you can't find the element because it doesn't exist until `.showModal` runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First you should only manipulate the `DOM` in angular with directives.  So your approach of accessing the DOM in this way would probably cause you problems even if it was working.*

That being said.  You just pass the scope value to the Modal and bind the value directly to the template with handlebars `{{custom_text}}`

**Update `.showModal` Method to pass scope values:**

```
ModalService.showModal({
  templateUrl: "notify.html",
  controller: "YesNoController",
  inputs: {
     'custom_text': $scope.custom_text
  }
}).then(function(modal) {
  modal.element.modal();
  modal.close.then(function(result) {
    $scope.message = result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No";
  });
});
```

**Modal HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
     <p><span id="my_text">{{custom_text}}</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just checked docs again, use of inputs is a good idea. But just for anyone other's reference, we cannot use that "inputs" parameter custom_text as it is in modal HTML. We have to pass it in modal controller and then access it as a scope property. Eg:

 `app.controller('YesNoController', ['$scope', 'close', 'custom_text', function($scope, close, custom_text) {
    $scope.my_text = custom_text;
}]);`

Now we can use my_text as in:

`<div class="modal-body">
        <p><span ng-bind="my_text"></span></p>
      </div>`